# Jasmine tests for Durandal events

Tags: jasmine, durandal, durandal-2.0

I was surprised that I didn't find any help in the documentation or a blog post about this.

I'm trying to add tests to make sure the eventing is setup correctly and stays that way.
The durandal app and events objects from Require are null. So there must be a setup step before they become available that I'm not aware of.

I have this Knockout view model:

```
define([
    'knockout',
    'durandal/events',
    'durandal/app',
    'Common/Modules/KoComponents/slideInEventListKeys'
],
function (ko, durandalEvents, durandalApp, slideInEventListKeys) {
 function SlideInVm(params) {
    // listen for anyone broadcasting this specific event.
    durandalEvents.includeIn(this);
    var _this = this;
    durandalApp.on(slideInEventListKeys.open).then(function () {
        _this.isShowing(true);
    });

    durandalApp.on(slideInEventListKeys.close).then(function () {
        _this.isShowing(false);
    });
  }
   SlideInVm.prototype.isShowing = ko.observable(false);
});
```

and in Jasmine:

```
define([
        'knockout',
        'Common/Modules/slideInVm',
        'durandal/events',
        'durandal/app',
        'Common/Modules/slideInEventListKeys'
],
function (ko, SlideInVm, durandalEvents, durandalApp, slideInEventListKeys) {
    'use strict';
    describe('Given the Slide In component', function () {
        var vm;
        beforeEach(function(){
          vm =  new SlideInVm();
        });
        it('Should subscribe for open events', function () {
                debugger;
                // events and app are null!
                // how to check this?
        });
        it('Should subscribe for close events', function () {

        });

        describe('When opening', function(){
            beforeEach(function(){
                // how to trigger this if app is null?
                app.trigger(slideInEventListKeys.open);
            });
            it('Should show the component', function(){
                expect(vm.isShowing()).toBeTruthy();
            });
        });
    });
});
```